# Open database connection to Qt/C++

Tags: c++, mysql, database, qt, database-connection

I have MySQL Server 8.0 (Workbanch), I'm tring to open a database using Qt/C++ (QSqlDatabase). But `db.open()`, returns `false` always. Why? I used `user: root` `pass: mypass`

```
Log from terminal:
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL  
QMYSQL3 QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7
db state:  false
```

paneldb.cpp

```
    #include "paneldb.h"
#include "ui_paneldb.h"

PanelDB::PanelDB(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::PanelDB)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    db.setHostName("localhost");
    db.setDatabaseName("testdb");
    db.setUserName("root");
    db.setPassword("mypass");

    bool ok = db.open();

    qDebug() << "db state: " << ok;
}

PanelDB::~PanelDB()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

paneldb.h

```
    #ifndef PANELDB_H
#define PANELDB_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QDebug>

namespace Ui {
class PanelDB;
}

class PanelDB : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit PanelDB(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~PanelDB();

private:
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    Ui::PanelDB *ui;
};

#endif // PANELDB_H
```

Pro file:

```
QT       += core gui
QT       += sql
```

MYSQL LOG:

```
mysql> SELECT CURRENT_USER();
+----------------+
| CURRENT_USER() |
+----------------+
|   root@localhost |
+----------------+

mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
| testdb             |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

How can I connect my DB using QT?

Comment: QMYSQL driver not loaded is the probable issue. Confirm by looking at QSqlDatabase::lastError().text()

Comment: You should build Qt SQL driver from sources for most drivers ... MySQL .. QODBC ..etc. don't rely on shipped installation drivers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the mysql client dll is in your PATH. If you dont have this one, then you have to install it on your platform first.